# Dynamically changing routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server. This is my `index.js`

```
let some_parameter = some_value;
const configuredHandler = new Handler(some_parameter);

const server = express();

server
    .get("*", configuredHandler.handleRequest)
    .post("*", configuredHandler.handleRequest)
    .put("*", configuredHandler.handleRequest)
    .delete("*", configuredHandler.handleRequest);
```

I am trying to update the routes if `some_parameter` to the `Handler` changes. So it should create a new instance of `configuredHandler` and the routes should automatically pick the new handler.
Ideally I want to be able to change `some_parameter` anywhere else in the code.
I am not sure how to structure it for this.
Please help.

Comment: Refer `express.Router` example [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). This helps to implement different router modules, which then can be registered in main router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is use something similar to a factory. That factory would create a new middleware every time `some_parameter` changes and save that middleware for future reference.

Whenever one of your routes is called, express would then refer to the current handler in your factory.

I wrote a simple example:

```
const express = require('express');

class HandlerFactory {

  static currentHandler = (req, res) => res.send('Hello');

  static setValue(value) {
    this.currentHandler = (req, res) => res.send(value);
  }

}

const app = express();
app.post('/change-value', (req, res) => {
  HandlerFactory.setValue(req.query.value);
  res.send();
});
app.use('/handler', (req, res) => HandlerFactory.currentHandler(req, res));

app.listen(3000);
```

Just run the app, then test its functionality:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000/handler
Hello
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/change-value?value=SecondMessage
$ curl http://localhost:3000/handler
SecondMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Router` module from [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

```
import { Router } from 'express';

const route1 = new Router();
const route2 = new Router();
const route3 = new Router();

route1.get('/', handler1);
route2.get('/', handler2);
route3.get('/', handler3);
..
..
// similarly define other HTTP routes


 const routeMap = {
  route1,
  route2
  route3
 }

 let some_parameter =  'route1';


 const server = express();
 const selectedRouter = routerMap[some_parameter];

 server.use('*', routerMap[some_parameter]);
```

I have a sample project on [Github](https://github.com/shankarregmi/api) that uses similar pattern

Comment: Thanks for the answer., but this will not work because depending on value of some_parameter I want to change the handler. So during initialisation I have default value for some_parameter but then it might change and the handler should change accordingly.